# Populate Class from List of Objects C#

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

First off I really hope I can describe exactly what I am looking for so if I am not clear please let me know and I will try my best to clarify.

I have two classes one being a small class which gets wrapped up into a list.
The second class uses values from the list.
Here is examples of the classes.

```
class FirstClass
{ 
    public string value1 {get; set; }
    public string value2 {get; set; }
    public string value3 {get; set; }
    public string value4 {get; set; }
    public string value5 {get; set; }
    public string value6 {get; set; }
}

class SecondClass
{
    public string FieldName { get; set; }
    public string FieldValue { get; set; }
}


List<SecondClass> sc = new List<SecondClass>();

sc[0].FieldName = "value1";
sc[0].FieldValue = "Hello World";
sc[1].FieldName = "value2";
sc[1].FieldValue = "Hello World";
sc[2].FieldName = "value3";
sc[2].FieldValue = "Hello World";
sc[3].FieldName = "value4";
sc[3].FieldValue = "Hello World";
sc[4].FieldName = "value5";
sc[4].FieldValue = "Hello World";
sc[5].FieldName = "value6";
sc[5].FieldValue = "Hello World";
```

Okay now you see the two Classes that are there and you see how the SecondClass List has two values to each object the first one being the name of the Field that matches the name of a field in the FirstClass and then the value you want to apply to the corresponding field in FirstClass.

So how do I transfer the values from one to the other?
God I really hope I cleared that up and did not make it too confusing.

---

EDIT EDIT EDIT

---

So I think I have a better way to explain this using the information above.

The SecondClass object in index 2

```
sc[2].FieldName = "value3";
sc[2].FieldValue = "Hello World";
```

needs to be assigned to FirstClass

So `sc[2].FieldName = "value3";`
in `FirstClass` their is an actual field named `value3` we need to assign the value of 
`sc[2].FieldValue = "Hello World";` to the `FirstClass` field `value3`

Hopefully that cleared it up a bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to use Reflection to accomplish your goal...i.e. `typeof(FirstClass).GetProperties`

In a static constructor of FirstClass I use Reflection to get a Dictionary of PropertyInfo instances.  I do this once and cache it for performance reasons.  Then when you call the method `SetValueByReflection` it looks up the proposed string value of the property in the dictionary and sets the value.

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<SecondClass> secondClasses = new List<SecondClass>();

        secondClasses.Add(new SecondClass { FieldName = "Value1", FieldValue = "Hello World 1" });
        secondClasses.Add(new SecondClass { FieldName = "Value2", FieldValue = "Hello World 2" });
        secondClasses.Add(new SecondClass { FieldName = "Value3", FieldValue = "Hello World 3" });
        secondClasses.Add(new SecondClass { FieldName = "Value4", FieldValue = "Hello World 4" });
        secondClasses.Add(new SecondClass { FieldName = "Value5", FieldValue = "Hello World 5" });
        secondClasses.Add(new SecondClass { FieldName = "Value6", FieldValue = "Hello World 6" });
        // secondClasses.Add(new SecondClass { FieldName = "Value7", FieldValue = "Hello World 7" }); // This line would throw an Exception

        FirstClass fc = new FirstClass();

        foreach (SecondClass secondClass in secondClasses)
        {
            fc.SetValueByReflection(secondClass.FieldName, secondClass.FieldValue);
        }
    }
}

class FirstClass
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<string, PropertyInfo> _publicProperties;

    static FirstClass()
    {
        const BindingFlags bindingFlags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.SetProperty;

        _publicProperties = typeof(FirstClass).GetProperties(bindingFlags).ToDictionary(propertyInfo => propertyInfo.Name);
    }

    public string Value1 { get; set; }
    public string Value2 { get; set; }
    public string Value3 { get; set; }
    public string Value4 { get; set; }
    public string Value5 { get; set; }
    public string Value6 { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the value of one of the properties of this class as specified by the propertyName parameter.
    /// </summary>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentException">Thrown when propertyName is not a valid property of FirstClass.</exception>
    public void SetValueByReflection(string propertyName, string value)
    {
        PropertyInfo propertyInfo;
        _publicProperties.TryGetValue(propertyName, out propertyInfo);

        if (propertyInfo != null)
        {
            propertyInfo.SetValue(this, value, null);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("FirstClass does not contain a property of the name " + propertyName, "propertyName");
        }
    }
}

class SecondClass
{
    public string FieldName { get; set; }
    public string FieldValue { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You are my Hero I thought I was going to have to a crazy for loop with a switch statement for a class that has 527 fields in it. That would have been extremely crazy amount of code and you just simplified it in some fairly elegant code. Thank you so much.

Comment: You're welcome.  I was thinking that this `ObjectDictionary<T>` might suit your needs as well...not 100% sure though.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mitsu/archive/2008/06/18/thinking-about-new-c-method-prototypes-object-as-dictionary.aspx (zip file for code at end of article)

Answer (score 4):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
FirstClass firstClass = new FirstClass(); // initialize with values.

List<SecondClass> list = 
    (from prop in FirstClass.GetType().GetProperties()
     select new SecondClass()
     {
         FieldName = prop.Name,
         FieldValue = prop.GetValue(firstClass, null)
     }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a great tool if you have to do lots of mapping from one object to another. Gives you a standard way of doing it.

[AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper)